# Show that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}3x+x^3e^y\\y-x^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)=(\begin{smallmatrix}u\\v\end{smallmatrix})$ has a unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Let 
$$T(x,y):=\begin{pmatrix}3x+x^3e^y\\y-x^2\end{pmatrix}, \,T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$$

How can  I show that $$\begin{pmatrix}3x+x^3e^y\\y-x^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$$ has a unique solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint - hope you can carry out the following steps:

- Write it as a system of two equations with two unknowns $x$ and $y$.
- Substitute $y$ from the second equation in the first equation, you will get something like $F(x)=u$ where $F$ is some complicated function of $x$.
- Prove that $F$ is a bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$:

  - State/prove that $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.
  - Prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=-\infty$.
  - Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\infty$.
  - Prove that $F$ is strictly increasing by proving that it is differentiable and $F'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
- Thus, $F(x)=u$ has a unique solution for $x$, which then gives you a unique solution for $y$.

Comment: Thanks! So in my example we have $y=v+x^2$ (coming from the second equation). Using your procedure we find a unique solution for $x$ and then plugging this $x$ into $y=v+x^2$ we get a unique solution for $y$?

I actually need to show that $T$ is a diffeomorphism. After showing that $T$ is bijective and continuously differentiable, I also need to show that $T^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable. Do you know a way to show this (probably without determining $T^{-1}$ but using some lemma instead)?

Comment: @user700332 It will follow from the fact that the function $F$ that you will find above is continuously differentiable and that its derivation is nonzero. (The expression of $x, y$ via $u, v$ will feature $F^{-1}$.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop you mean "that its derivative is nonzero", right ?

Comment: I found the following in my book: Let $f:C\to D$ be bijective and continuously differentiable with open $C\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and arbitrary $D \subseteq \mathbb R^d$. If the gradient $\nabla f$ is invertible for all $x \in C$, then it follows that $D$ is open and $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable. In my case:

$T$ is bijective and continuously differentiable, $\mathbb R^2$ is open. $\nabla T$ has determinant $\neq 0$ so $T^{-1}$ should also be continuously differentiable if I didn't miss out on anything

Comment: @user700332 Yep, this should do as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that I consider the solution given by @Stinking Bishop as much too vague (for example, we have no longer two parameters but a single one...).

Instead, let us consider first a graphical representation of curves :

$$3x+x^3e^y=u \  \ \ \text{and} \ \  \ y-x^2=v\tag{1}$$

for a certain range of values of $u$ and $v$.

[image]

*Fig 1 : The black curves corresponding to the first equation are symmetrical for opposite values of $u$ ; the positive values of $u$ give the decreasing curves. The blue curves correspond to the second family of equations (parabolas).*

The symmetry evidenced by this figure allows WLOG to **consider only positive values of $x$ and $u$.**

Let us re-write (1) under the form of cartesian equations :

$$y:=f_u(x)=\ln\left(\dfrac{u-3x}{x^3}\right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ y:=g_v(x)=x^2+v$$

(being understood that $0<x<u/3$ for the first function).

It is easy to see that on this domain $(0,u/3)$, $f_u'(x)=\dfrac{-3(u+4x)}{x(u-3x)}$ is negative (therefore $f_u$ is decreasing), whereas $g_v$ has always a positive derivative, therefore increasing.

As $\lim_{x \to 0} f_u(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to u/3-} f_u(x)=-\infty$, and, besides, $g_v(0)=0$ these curves have a unique intersection point, whatever $u$ and $v$ (for the sake of precision, apply intermediate value theorem to the difference function $f_u-g_v$ whose derivative is negative thus decreasing from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ on domain $(0,u/3)$).